# How to import SQLite database into Hadoop HDFS

Tags: sqlite, hadoop

I would like to import the SQLite databases into hadoop hdfs. These databases are from mobile app database and I would like to import multiple databases daily into HDFS.

Comment: What is the question and how does it pertain to this site?

Answer (score 3):

You could try importing your database into **HDFS** using **Sqoop**.

Try this (after installing sqoop and making necessary configuration):

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/database/databasename.db --table tablename --m 1 --target-dir /directory/name/in/hdfs --driver org.sqlite.JDBC
```

> **NOTE:** You will need to download and copy **sqlite-jdbc-x.x.x.jar** to your **Sqoop lib** and **Hadoop lib** folder.

You will also need to add sqlite-jdbc-x.x.x.jar to your hadoop classpath (in case if you get class not found error). Add this line in your `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/full/path/to/sqlite/jar
```

If you have sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar in your `/usr/local/sqlite` folder, then add like this:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

Comment: GOT ERROR  Rajesh N          
15/05/21 15:35:38 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
15/05/21 15:35:38 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc:sqlite://home/pbsi/Downloads/arjun_pbs.db
 at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:191)
 at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:256)

Comment: Remove one `/` before `home` from `jdbc:sqlite://home/pbsi/Downloads/arjun_pbs.db`. It should be like this: `jdbc:sqlite:/home/pbsi/Downloads/arjun_pbs.db`.Now, try sqoop command. Also, did you add `sqlite-jdbc` jar in your classpath?

Comment: yes I added sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar in sqoop lib and After removing  /  Still getting the same error

Comment: Try adding `--driver org.sqlite.JDBC` in sqoop command. I have updated the answer.

Comment: ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: SQLite supports only TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE and TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED.
java.sql.SQLException: SQLite supports only TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE and TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED

Comment: I'm having the same error, ran across this bug report on setting isolation. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2415

Comment: Did anyone get this working in the last three years? Or is SqLite still not supported, as mentioned by myuce?

Answer (score 1):

As it is said [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Requirements-and-Supported-Versions/cdhrsv_db.html), sqoop currently does not support SQLite.

Comment: [Here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal) it says "You can use Sqoop with any other JDBC-compliant database.

Comment: Have you tried with JDBC? I did not, but will give it a go when have time.

Comment: Could not try yet. Still waiting for our IT to provide the HDP Sandbox to get started.

Comment: Just curious, still using HDP? Why?

Comment: Maybe because I don't know about better alternatives. :) What should I use in your opinion to get started with spark and hdfs on a virtual machine?

Comment: If windows, cannot say anything. Is it on windows? May be because it is easier to setup... Better UIs... At the end, you will better be working on linux with Cloudera; But its UI/manager requires payment..  It is up to you.